# Three maven related problems for Intellij IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA, and I am using 12.1.4.

I tried to create a maven project, and then add two sub modules.

This is the project structure:

[image]

As you can see,the `mavenapp` is the root project(parent project), while the `app-common` and `app-web` are the sub modules.

IntelliJ IDEA does the right thing by modify the pom.xml of `mavenapp`:

```
<modules>
    <module>app-common</module>
    <module>app-web</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Now I have some problems:

1) make `app-common` as a dependency of `app-web`?

That's to say, I want to IntelliJ IDEA modify the pom.xml of `app-web`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-common</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I can not find how to make it?

By reading the docs at the [help site](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-maven-dependencies.html), but I can not find the `app-common` module at the `Maven Artifact Search` dialog box.

2) extract the repeated dependencies to the `dependencyManagement` of the pom.xml of  the parent

While I mean if the `app-common` and `app-webapp` have some same dependencies, for example, the `junit` dependency.

It would be better if we define the `junt` in the `dependencyManagement` of the pom.xml of `mavenapp`, I wonder if the IDE can make it for us?

3) can the idea files can be hidden.

I mean the files generated by the IDE like the  folder of `.idea` can be hidden in the `project` window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) Ctrl-Alt-M (extract managed dependency) does the job for you.

3) You have to go to Settings->File Types and add '*.iml;*.idea;*.iws;*.ipr;' to ignored files and folders (at the bottom)

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where to press the short keys?

Comment: on 2) anywhere in the dependency decleration

Comment: `Alt-Enter` just add the dependency `app-common` to `app-web` which does not modify the `app-web/pom.xml`.   2) `Ctrl-Alt-M` does not work.

Comment: you are absolutely right on Alt-Enter, sorry for that. Do you have the possibility to click by mouse: Refactor->Extract->Extract Managed Dependency when you are inthe dependency decleartion?